# How do I get the MouseMove mouse event from TabControl?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol, mousemove, contenttemplate

The problem is that when the mouse moves through the `ListBox`, it should follow a crosshair of two intersecting lines. Code Xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Drawing_TabControl"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Background="WhiteSmoke"
                        SelectionChanged="Drawing_TabControl_SelectionChanged"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile_M}"
                        MouseLeftButtonDown="Drawing_TabControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        MouseMove="Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Drawing_TabControl_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:File_M}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name_File}" Background="Transparent" />
                            <Button Height="18"
                                    Width="18"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    Click="Close_TabItem"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource B2V}}">
                                <Image  Source="icons\close_x.png"/>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:File_M}">
                        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                                <ListBox x:Name="a"
                                         Background="GhostWhite"
                                         Height="6cm"
                                         Width="16cm"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
                                         Tag="listbox">
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <Canvas />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:Figure_M}">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Line x:Name="hor"
                                                      X1="0"
                                                      Y1="{Binding Path=YMove}"
                                                      X2="500"
                                                      Y2="{Binding Path=YMove}"
                                                      Stroke="DarkRed"
                                                      StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                                                <Line x:Name="ver"
                                                      X1="{Binding Path=XMove}"
                                                      Y1="0"
                                                      X2="{Binding Path=XMove}"
                                                      Y2="100"
                                                      Stroke="DarkRed"
                                                      StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

            </TabControl>
```

Code C#:

```
private void Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tag = "listbox";
            var figure_M = sender as Figure_M;

                figure_M.XMove = e.GetPosition(Drawing_TabControl).X;
                figure_M.YMove = e.GetPosition(Drawing_TabControl).Y;

        }
```

Currently throws an exception when the mouse hovers over `TabItem`: `System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference does not point to an instance of the object."`

Comment: In `Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove` sender is `TabControl`.

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi ```private void Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tag = "listbox";
            var tab = sender as TabControl;
            var figure_M = sender as Figure_M;
            
                figure_M.XMove = e.GetPosition(tab).X;
                figure_M.YMove = e.GetPosition(tab).Y;
            
        } ``` it doesn't work, the same error.

Comment: You can not cast sender as `Figure_M`.

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi Thank you, the Error has disappeared, but I don't understand how to get mouse coordinates from the` ListBox x:Name="a"` template yet.

Comment: It's seem you try to change x,y of two lines (hor, ver). but i can't figure out why you need get mouse coordinates from the `ListBox x:Name="a"`. please edit your question and explain your porpuse and problem. may be i can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi please see my video - https://youtu.be/9NXfW1le9fE . I need make in `TabControl` also as in down `Canvas`

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi Please see again video - https://youtu.be/wy6n9v3klEY

Comment: I'm so sorry. your work is a great job. but please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I can say you to handle mouse move for `Grid Background="WhiteSmoke"`, BUT NOTE this is an incorrect help, because i can't figure out your problem correctly.